# How to find outliers according to differences?

Tags: python-3.x, row, difference

I want to find the outliers in my calculations of river kilometers by checking the difference between 2 values,
I have written the code like this:

```
df['diff_to_traj'] = df.river_km.diff()

df2 = df[(df.diff_to_traj < 3) & (df.diff_to_traj > -3)]
print(df2.diff_to_traj.min())
```

But the problem occurs when 2 to outliers are in dataframe one by one:

```
river_km
1205.2538515545893
1205.2485826441855
1617.967972499492
1617.971987093596
1205.13808290652
1205.1338783988865


diff_to_traj
-0.005233850539070772
-0.005268910403856353
412.7193898553064
0.004014594104091884
-412.8339041870761
-0.004204507633403409
```

So in my case the outliers are 2 values

```
1617.967972499492,
1617.971987093596
```

but with this approach of 
difference riever_km i can not detec them both

How to calculate differences and check tahat if it less then 3 km it is good when the diff is biger delete row and the next value compare with previous row.

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I want to find high outliers is getting a certain percentile of the data and checking the values that are considerably higher than that percentile.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```py
n = 1.20
q = 0.6
outliers = df['river_km'] > n*df['river_km'].quantile(q)
outliers
```

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: river_km, dtype: bool
```

where it finds the rows that are at least 20% higher than the 60th percentile of your data. It usually works like a charm for me.

You'll probably have to tinker around with the 'n' and 'q' values if you want good detection, though.

Comment: In my case it didnt work, because my values reduse from higher value to lower and variates from 0 to 1500
I think the only case is to find the differences between two values

Comment: You'll probably need something more local then. Maybe [scipy.signal.find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)? I have never used it, but it seems like it would fit your problem. Or maybe use the method I presented, but in a rolling window rather than a global check.